# Cordova - Android - Find newest file on USB storage

Tags: java, android, cordova, cordova-plugins

I am writing a plugin for Android in Java. One function is to detect USB storage attach and return path to this USB storage. This code is working properly, but I have a problem with second function which should get this path from the first function (e.g. /storage/BA4862GJI), list all files in the root of this USB and return newest file with given extension (e.g. .txt).
From Android 11 permission `MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` is not enough anymore. Can you please guide me how to get proper permissions and get list of the files? The function to get all files with given extension goes like this:

```
private List<File> getFilesWithExtension(File directory, final String extension) {
    try {
        List<File> found =  Files.walk(directory.toPath(), 1)
                .filter(p -> {
                    try {
                        return Files.isRegularFile(p) && Files.isReadable(p);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        return false;
                    }
                })
                .filter(file -> file.getFileName().toString().endsWith(extension))
                .map(Path::toFile)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
        return found;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("USBManager", "Failed to retrieve files with extension: " + e.getMessage());
        return new ArrayList<>();
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: `which should get this path from the first function (e.g. /storage/BA4862GJI), ` Please. You should have started with that function.

Comment: `/storage/BA4862GJI)` No. A UUID will never look like that.

Comment: This function is working. Given path is just an example, don´t know the precise uuid of the USB storage, I was able to locate it in Android Studio file tree, tested it with File rootFolder = new File(rootFolderPath); rootFolder.exists();, ... but rootFolder.canRead() returns false and when I tried to list files, I got AccessDeniedException.

Answer (score 1):

You should get the path from `getExternalFilesDirs()`.

And if that function does not deliver path to usb drive then you have to use SAF with `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE` and let the user choose the drive.

Comment: getExternalFilesDirs() returns paths to external files of my own package:
- /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.package.example/files
- /storage/42C0A57FC0A579B5/Android/data/com.package.example/files
What I was asking for was the root of the USB storage and there list of the files. As you can see, the url was correct (in this case /storage/42C0A57FC0A579B5), but needed access to this folder to read the list.

Comment: It wil return two paths if a micro-sd card is inserted. And three if also a usb drive attached. If it does not return the usb drive then.. well read my answer.

Comment: I eddited the the comment above (did not expect the reply this fast :) ) The path is there, but not that I wanted.

Comment: If there is no micro-sd inserted and you get two paths then the second one is of the usb drive. And why dont you tell if there is a micro-sd inserted?

Comment: Tell if the second one if from a micro-sd card or from the usb drive.

Comment: Yes, the second one is from usb drive.

Comment: There is no micro-sd card. But I believe we don´t understand each other. My original request was to gain access and eventuely copy the file I need from the root of the USB, I already have the path to, but I need to find the file in the root first. So I need to implement a search function first. But as I have written, in the root of the USB storage.

Comment: Well then you are lucky. Now you know the root of the drive.

Comment: Yes, I already now that from the USB attach detection. The root is /storage/42C0A57FC0A579B5, but I cannot list the files there.

Comment: Then what exactly is the problem. Tell what goes wrong. Dont let us guess. Did you implement READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission?

Comment: 42C0A57FC0A579B5 is pretty strange. Never saw such an uuid. It always looks like 42C0-AB54 here.

Comment: Have you used File.exists() and File.canRead() on it?

Comment: Yes I did, problem is, as I have mentioned earlier, that from Android 11 I believe, READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission is not working. I even implemented Intent for Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_APP_ALL_FILES_ACCESS_PERMISSION, but still no luck. I still get AccessDeniedException.

Comment: That permission is needed for 10, 11,12. Not for 13.

Comment: Yes, I have tried ... File.exists() was true, but File.canRead() was false.

Comment: I am working on android 11 right now.

Comment: Just to let you know, I have managed to make it work. Problem was somewhere in the devices firmware. As it is custom hardware from the company we have collaboration with, they send me new firmware and everything works as it should.